# malformed pom error with maven war plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am getting a malformed POM, unrecognised tag manifest on this plugin,

documentation supports the implementation so i don't understand what to do to fix this.

Thanks.

**Header:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> ```

**Plugin:**

> ```
> <build>
>     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
>     <pluginManagement>
>         <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <manifest>
>                     <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
>                 </manifest>
>                 <archive>
>                     <manifestEntries>
>                         <Specification-Title>${project.name}</Specification-Title>
>                         <Release-Version>${release.version}</Release-Version>
>                         <Release-Type>${RELEASE_TYPE}</Release-Type>
>                         <Build-Number>${BUILD_NUMBER}</Build-Number>
>                     </manifestEntries>
>                 </archive>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </pluginManagement>
> </build>
>
>
> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]   
> [ERROR]   The project com.X.server:X:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (...pom.xml) has 1 error
> [ERROR]     Malformed POM ...pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'manifest' (position: START_TAG seen ...</artifactId>\n                    <manifest>... @220:31)  @ ...pom.xml, line 220, column 31 -> [Help 2]
> [ERROR] 
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<manifest>` element should be *inside* the `<archive>` element.

E.g., 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html